# fetch those mysql rows which dont have entry in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timetable

i have a timetable application and i'm stuck at a point. now while allotting a slot to a teacher i need to display only those rooms which are vacant based on certain conditions i.e. the day and period coordinates(x,y) and the semesters which means the even semesters (2,4,6) cannot have classes in that room at same time and same is for the odd semesters(1,3,5).

my table structure:

```
Room table
roomid, roomname

papers table
id, semster, papername

ttresponsibility table(this is the one where we store the allocations)
id, teacherid, day, period, subjectid, room
```

Now my requirement is to fetch only those rooms at the time of allocation which are vacant. this ofcourse should be while selecting for a teacher and the course, semester and the paper has been selected. my idea is to populate the rooms dropdown on the onchange event of paper dropdown. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: so what is it that you have tried ?

Comment: honestly, i havent tried anything but have a couple of ideas like using the NOT IN operator in mysql or use left join. i am working on these as we speak.

Comment: please try and post your code , as here we would to help you with some work of yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get there:

```
SELECT roomname
FROM Room
WHERE roomid NOT IN
(
    SELECT roomid
    FROM ttresponsibility
    WHERE period = *insert_timeperiod_to_search_for_empty_rooms_here*
        AND day = *insert_day_to_search_for_empty_rooms_here*
)
```

Comment: thanks i'll just try that and post abt the success.

Comment: and what do u think abt using a left join here?

Comment: For a left join you could do:  SELECT roomname
    FROM Room  
    LEFT JOIN ttresponsibility t ON on Room.roomid = t.roomid and period = *insert_timeperiod_to_search_for_empty_rooms_here* 
            AND day = *insert_day_to_search_for_empty_rooms_here*
 WHERE t.id IS NULL

Comment: but isnt it the same thing that u gave in your answer

Comment: the left join gave me an empty resultset.

Comment: the query i used : SELECT rooms.room_id as rid,rooms.room as name FROM rooms LEFT JOIN ttresponsibility t ON rooms.room_id = t.room where t.period = '6' AND t.day = '4' and t.resp_id IS NULL

Comment: thanks a ton. NOT IN worked perfectly. thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, my bad on the LEFT JOIN.  It didn't work because it was matching into the left joined table for period and day, but I was also telling it to only return rooms which did NOT match in the left joined table.  Result:  nothing to return.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21094/discussion-between-dwright-and-nikhil-verma), if needed.